# Using jQuery .animate on hover to display new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hover, jquery-animate

The function is working correctly, however the div to the right disappears before I can click on any link. 
Should I incorporate a mouse event to get this to work almost like a sideways drop down menu?

```
$(".design").hover(function () {
$(".design-nav").animate({opacity: "1"}, {queue: false});
}, function () {
$(".design-nav").animate({opacity: "0"}, {queue: false});
});

<div class="design"></div>
<div class="design-nav">
<div><li href="#">link</li></div>
<div><li href="#">link</li></div>
<div><li href="#">link</li></div>
</div>
```

Or see working demo here -
http://jsfiddle.net/conordaltonlive/jfLNh/3/

Comment: No, simply add a timeout so that the mouseleave on design will hide the design-nav div after 10ms, and if the design-nav div is hovered over, then clear that timeout so that it doesn't hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".design,.design-nav").hover(function () {
    $(".design-nav").animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
}, function () {
    $(".design-nav").animate({
        opacity: "0"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
});
```

And also change your `.design-nav` css `opacity:0`

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfLNh/7/)

Answer (score 0):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/jfLNh/9/)**

Try this

Wrap your div together inside another here it is `<div id="container">` and apply hover on it, so it works, otherwise if you move away from your hover div , the visible div will hide.

### html

```
<div id="container">    // added div
<div class="design"></div>
<div class="design-nav">
    <div><li href="#">link</li></div>
    <div><li href="#">link</li></div>
    <div><li href="#">link</li></div>
</div>
</div>
```

### code

```
$("#container").hover(function () { // changed selector '.design' to '#container'
    $(".design-nav").animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
}, function () {
    $(".design-nav").animate({
        opacity: "0"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
});
```

and changed `opacity: 0;`of class `.design-nav` inorder to hide it on page load

Hope this helps,thank you